# Using shared serial modem

Tags: linux, solaris, tty, modem, pty

I'm trying to use on Solaris box modem connected to Linux box via serial port.

Sharing is made from socat.

Server command(linux):

```
socat tcp-l:54321,reuseaddr,fork file:/dev/ttyXXX0,nonblock,waitlock=/var/run/ttyXXX0.lock
```

Client command(solaris):

```
/usr/local/bin/socat -s pty,link=/dev/virtualmodem0,ignoreeof,raw,echo=0 tcp:192.168.56.2:54321
```

The problem is that, when I try to execute tip I get an error.

```
tip softwire
tip: /dev/virtualmodem0: not a tty
all ports busy
```

So how can I use port shared by socat with tip?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `socat` on the client if you are using `tip` on the client. You only need one or the other.

Comment: socat is used to provide /dev/virtualmodem0 from linux box with modem connected via serial port to solaris box without serial port. tip was used only as testing connection between those two before configuring modem connection on solaris box